# Linq Select into --> "if" or "Case when" using in where condition

Tags: c#, linq

in this value "overdueDays", I would like to fetch 0 if this field is null.

Thanks.
[image: Code Is Here]

Comment: add code as code text. don't need to add external image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this.

```
overdueDays = g.Any(x => x.AdatGun < 0) ? your code here: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator).

> The **??** operator is called the **null-coalescing operator**. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

You code would look like this.

```
overdueDays = g.Where(x => x.Adatgun < 0).Sum(x => x.AdatTutar) /
              g.Where(x => x.AdatGun < 0).Sum(x => x.DocLastTotal) ?? 0,
averageDebtorDate = ....
```